# Should immutable global objects be declared as 'const my_result_t BLAH;' or 'extern const my_result_t BLAH;'?

Tags: c++, singleton, extern

First, some motivating background info; I'm experimenting with the idea of representing error-codes (returned from functions) as super-lightweight human-readable-strings rather than enum-integers, something like this:

```
#include <string.h>

/** Ultra-lightweight type for returning the success/error status from a function. */
class my_result_t
{
public:
   /** Default constructor, creates a my_result_t indicating success */
   my_result_t() : _errorString(NULL) {/* empty */}

   /** Constructor for returning an error-result */
   my_result_t(const char * s) : _errorString(s) {/* empty */}

   /** Returns true iff the result was "success" */
   bool IsOK() const {return (_errorString == NULL);}

   /** Returns true iff the result was an error of some type */
   bool IsError() const {return (_errorString != NULL);}

   /** Return a human-readable description of the result */
   const char * GetDescription() const {return _errorString ? _errorString : "Success";}

   /** Returns true iff the two objects are equivalent */
   bool operator ==(const my_result_t & rhs) const
   {
      return _errorString ? ((rhs._errorString)&&(strcmp(_errorString, rhs._errorString) == 0)) : (rhs._errorString == NULL);
   }

   /** Returns true iff the two objects are not equivalent */
   bool operator !=(const my_result_t & rhs) const {return !(*this==rhs);}

private:
   const char * _errorString;
};

my_result_t SomeFunction()
{
   FILE * fp = fopen("some_file.txt", "r");
   if (fp)
   {
      fclose(fp);
      return my_result_t();  // success!
   }
   else return my_result_t("File not Found");
}

int main(int, char **)
{
   printf("SomeFunction returned [%s]\n", SomeFunction().GetDescription());
   return 0;
}
```

... the idea being that instead of having to maintain a centralized registry of "official" error codes somewhere, any function could simply return a string describing their particular error-condition in a human-readable fashion.  Since `sizeof(my_result_t)==sizeof(const char *)`, this shouldn't be significantly less efficient than the traditional return-an-integer-error-code convention that e.g. POSIX likes to use.  (I do have to be careful not to return pointers-to-temporary-char-buffers, of course)

... all that works reasonably well; my question concerns the subsequent refinement, which is the creation of some global `my_result_t` definitions for certain common error-types, e.g.:

```
const my_result_t RESULT_OUT_OF_MEMORY("Out of Memory");
const my_result_t RESULT_ACCESS_DENIED("Access Denied");  
const my_result_t RESULT_BAD_ARGUMENT("Bad Argument");  
const my_result_t RESULT_FILE_NOT_FOUND("File not Found");  
[...]
```

... that way the author of `SomeFunction()` could just `return RESULT_FILE_NOT_FOUND;` rather than being required to enter a custom error-string and risk typos, inconsistency with other function's result-strings for the same type of error, etc.

My question is, what is the most runtime-efficient way to declare these common/global result-codes?

One way to do it would be to make them 'singleton objects', like this:

```
// my_result_t.h  
extern const my_result_t RESULT_OUT_OF_MEMORY("Out of Memory");
extern const my_result_t RESULT_ACCESS_DENIED("Access Denied");  
extern const my_result_t RESULT_BAD_ARGUMENT("Bad Argument");  
extern const my_result_t RESULT_FILE_NOT_FOUND("File not Found");  

// my_result_t.cpp
const my_result_t RESULT_OUT_OF_MEMORY("Out of Memory");
const my_result_t RESULT_ACCESS_DENIED("Access Denied");  
const my_result_t RESULT_BAD_ARGUMENT("Bad Argument");  
const my_result_t RESULT_FILE_NOT_FOUND("File not Found");
```

... or the other way, is to simply put the following in a central header file:

```
// my_result_t.h  
const my_result_t RESULT_OUT_OF_MEMORY("Out of Memory");
const my_result_t RESULT_ACCESS_DENIED("Access Denied");  
const my_result_t RESULT_BAD_ARGUMENT("Bad Argument");  
const my_result_t RESULT_FILE_NOT_FOUND("File not Found");
```

... this latter way seems to work fine, but I'm not 100% confident it's kosher to do that; for one thing, it means that e.g. RESULT_OUT_OF_MEMORY is a separate object in every translation unit, which seems like it might put stress on the linker to de-duplicate, or even invoke conceivably undefined behavior (I'm not sure how the One Definition Rule applies here).  On the other hand, using the "extern" approach means that the actual contents of the `my_result_t` objects are only available to optimizer when compiling `my_result_t.cpp`, and not when compiling any other functions that reference these objects, which means the optimizer might not be able do inlining-optimizations.

Is one approach better than the other, from the perspective of correctness, but also helping the optimizer to make the code as efficient as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Const namespace scope variables should have default internal linkage, so it is correct to write `const my_result_t RESULT_XXX;` in the header:

> The const qualifier used on a declaration of a non-local non-volatile
>   non-template non-inline variable that is
>   not declared extern gives it internal linkage. This is different from
>   C where const file scope variables have external linkage.

Also, having external symbols used in a function, most likely, would not prevent it from being inline-optimized, since the compiler would unpack the function in place, leave any external symbols in an as-is manner. These symbols are then resolved by the linker. However compilers implementations can vary so no definite word can be said about this. That said, using `extern const` would most likely not cause any trouble for inline optimization. (I tried with msvc, hinted inline with `__inline` keyword, and the emitted assembly shows that `SomeFunction()` got inlined).

I would suggest using the `extern const` approach since there will be only one instance for each result object.

Below was my original answer, which is good to have if you use c++ 17 (with `extern const` you will have to write things twice: definition and then declaration, but not if you are using `inline` variables)

---

C++ 17 has been shipped with some features you need. Essentially, we can build the `my_result_t` class with `string_view`, `constexpr` and `inline` variable. I have done some modification to your code:

```cpp
// ErrorCode.h

#pragma once
#include <string_view>
/** Ultra-lightweight type for returning the success/error status from a function. */
class my_result_t
{
public:
    /** Default constructor, creates a my_result_t indicating success */
    constexpr my_result_t() : _errorString{} {/* empty */ }

    /** Constructor for returning an error-result */
    constexpr my_result_t(const char* s) : _errorString(s) {/* empty */ }

    /** Returns true iff the result was "success" */
    constexpr bool IsOK() const { return (_errorString.data() == nullptr); }

    /** Returns true iff the result was an error of some type */
    constexpr bool IsError() const { return (_errorString.data() != nullptr); }

    /** Return a human-readable description of the result */
    constexpr std::string_view GetDescription() const { return _errorString.data() ? _errorString : "Success"; }

    /** Returns true iff the two objects are equivalent */
    constexpr bool operator ==(const my_result_t& rhs) const
    {
        return _errorString.data() ? ((rhs._errorString.data()) && 
            (_errorString == rhs._errorString)) : (rhs._errorString.data() == nullptr);
    }

    /** Returns true iff the two objects are not equivalent */
    constexpr bool operator !=(const my_result_t& rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); }

private:
    std::string_view _errorString;
};

inline constexpr my_result_t RESULT_SUCCESS{};
inline constexpr my_result_t RESULT_OUT_OF_MEMORY("Out of Memory");
inline constexpr my_result_t RESULT_ACCESS_DENIED("Access Denied");
inline constexpr my_result_t RESULT_BAD_ARGUMENT("Bad Argument");
inline constexpr my_result_t RESULT_FILE_NOT_FOUND("File not Found");

// main.cpp

#include "ErrorCode.h"
#include <iostream>

inline my_result_t SomeFunction()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("some_file.txt", "r");
    if (fp)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return RESULT_SUCCESS;  // success!
    }
    else return RESULT_FILE_NOT_FOUND;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << SomeFunction().GetDescription();
    return 0;
}
```

[Compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/4iJE3_)

In the code, every translation unit share the same result objects, because:

> An inline function or variable with external linkage
>   (e.g. not declared static) has the following additional properties:
>
> 1) It must be declared inline in every translation unit.
>
> 2) **It has the same address in every translation unit.**

<strike>And it does not affect inlining of functions using the objects, since they are essentially just compile time constants!</strike>

The only drawback is that `string_view` bigger in size (approximately two times than a const char pointer, depending on implementation). However, this can be avoided by implementing a `constexpr` "strcmp" function:

```cpp
constexpr bool strings_equal(char const* a, char const* b) {
    return a == nullptr ? (b == nullptr) : (b != nullptr && std::string_view(a) == b);
}
```

And then you can happily use `const char *` in your result class instead of `string_view`!